# startMethodTracing maximum buffer size

Tags: android

What defines the maximum buffer size that `startMethodTracing` allows?

I though it was the device's amount of RAM available, but now I'm testing with a android-x86 image on a virtual machine that has (usually) 3,3GB of free RAM and I can't set the buffer size larger than 1,125GB (can be a little bit more but less than 1,25GB). On a real device of its 550MB of free RAM I could use +-400MB for the buffer size.